# align widgets in the dashboard?

Tags: dashboard-widget

Is it possible to move a dashboard widget to a specific coordinate? I looked in google, and there's no specific answer to it.

I asume that there should be some plist file somewhere with the numeric coordinates of each widget that can be programatically set using automator or something.

Comment: Could you be more specific what you actually trying to do.

Comment: Just grab one of my widgets in the dashboard and center it in the screen... :P